# Getting cannot read property '0' of null in a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the filename from an url. I'm doing this:

```
console.log(url)
const filename = url.match(/([^\/]+)(?=\.\w+$)/)[0]
return filename
```

But I get `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`. Which is strange, because `console.log(url)` outputs the `file: http://ac-0uhksb6K.clouddn.com/9710016c8dfcf6ae1e9d.jpg?imageView2/2/w/4096/h/2048/q/100/format/jpg`

What could be the problem?

Comment: There is no match, see https://regex101.com/r/nX2rP5/1. Check if the match is not null first. Try `([^\/]+)\.\w+(?:\?|$)` and access `[1]` item.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you were right! Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex expects the filename with its extension to be the last part of a URL, while the URL in the question has also query parameters. In order to take these into account add the `(?:$|\?)` alternation to the lookahead:

```
[^\/]+(?=\.\w+(?:$|\?))
```

Note: the capture group is redundant so removed it as well.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nX2rP5/3

Comment: In this case, you have a redundant capturing group. Why use both, capturing group around the whole consuming pattern and the lookaround?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Just made minimal change to the OP's expression. Fixing the post...

Answer (score 1):

If there are no matches, then there is no array on which to select the first item with [0].

You'll want to check the array has at least one item first...

Comment: I think the simplest way to do that is to index it without the [] operator, using the "?." like this: str.match(...)?.at(0) this returns the value or undefined, and never throws an error.

Comment: Yes looks good. Wasn’t possible back when I wrote my answer I don’t think? That’s a php 8 thing.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because there is no match, see [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nX2rP5/1). The issue is that the lookahead `(?=\.\w+$)` requires the `.`+`1 or more word chars` *before the end of string `$`*. You need to allow checking the `?` query string start marker, too.

**NOTE** that you actually do not have to use lookarounds at all. Use a capturing group - `([^\/]+)\.\w+(?:\?|$)` and access `[1]` item.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bI3sR6/1)

Also, it is always a good idea to check if a match occurred at all before accessing capture groups.

```js
var re = /([^\/]+)\.\w+(?:\?|$)/; 
var str = 'file: http://ac-0uhksb6K.clouddn.com/9710016c8dfcf6ae1e9d.jpg?imageView2/2/w/4096/h/2048/q/100/format/jpg';
var match = str.match(re);
if (match) {
   console.log(match[1]);
}
```